# Form bean to session variable

Tags: struts, tags

If i can use

```
<td><textarea><bean:write name="smlMoverDetailForm" property="empFDJoiningDate"/>
</textarea></td>
```

to displace a value how can i use the struts tags to save a vaiable to the sesssion

in sudo code

```
session.setAttribute("test" , "<bean:write name="smlMoverDetailForm"
property="empFDJoiningDate"/>");
```

is this possible?

Comment: To increase readability:
displace => display
sudo => pseudo

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.
Struts tags are only available in jsp pages.

But you can do something like this:

if the bean smlMoverDetailForm is in scope request

```
session.setAttribute("test",((THECLASSOFTHEBEAN)request.getAttribute("smlMoverDetailForm")).getEmpFDJoiningDate());
```

else if the bean smlMoverDetailForm is in scope session

```
session.setAttribute("test",((THECLASSOFTHEBEAN)request.getSession().getAttribute("smlMoverDetailForm")).getEmpFDJoiningDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Late but possible. You can set the session scope to your form bean in `struts-config.xml` file when you map the action.